# Why my Pytorch Doesn't raise overflow/underflow warning during the running

Tags: pytorch

Consider

> torch.Tensor([torch.exp(torch.Tensor([10000]))])

it gives

> tensor([inf.])

without raising any warning or error. During the training, many time I end up with nan value; and have to debug all the way to figure when did the numerical issue occurs.

Is there anyway to fix it

I'm using pytorch 0.4.0

(Both jupyter notebook and pycharm doesn't give any numerical warning)

Comment: I had also issues with this, it can be very annoying to track back the issue. I think the best thing you can do is opening a issue on pytorch GitHub site.

Comment: For further discussion (posted on pytorch forums by OP): https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-setup-numerical-warning/18091/3